# Универсальный код для permission во всех версиях API

Tags: android

У меня проблема с разрешениями permission в Android

До 23 версии разрешения указывались только в манифесте, после стали как в iOS еще и программно писать для того, чтобы человек подтверждал разрешения.

Как проще и удобнее сделать так, чтобы работало и для 23+, и для 22-? Ну уж слишком все запутанно и слишком большой код получается, чтобы просто включить разрешения, допустим, на запись в карту памяти.

С Новым Годом!

Comment: проще выставить targetApi в 22 и не заморачиваться. По факту - для 22- работает манифест, для выше - запросы разрешений во время работы. Надо совмещать.

Comment: @pavel я тоже хотел предложить выставлять `targetSdkVersion` в `22`, но как тогда будет работать это приложение (без кода запроса разрешения) на устройстве с 23+?

Comment: Получается что для 22 надо в манифесте писать как раньше, а для 23+ все таки придеться программно это все делать?Это же столько времени уйдет на каждое разрешение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой, если не хотите писать много одинакового кода. Для этого есть куча разных, но рекомендую вам [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, в доках написано, что если минимальный апи  ниже чем андроид 6.0, то при установке на 6.0 и выше разрешения будут спрашивать всем скопом при установке и можно не использовать runtime permissions